# Problem in displaying the history of the Comments field inside my List views

Tags: list, development, list-view, custom-list, view-styles

I have added an Issue tracking list to my team site, which provides a build-in field for displaying the history of the list comments (*i rename the built-in column to be named Latest Updates instead of comments*)as follow:-

[image]

But when I chose to display this column inside my list view as follow:-

[image]

The results is that I will get a link named “View entities”, instead of showing the history records, as follow:-

[image]

Can anyone advice on this please, on how i can display the history records instead of the "View Entities" link?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the xsl of the view and make following change

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@LatestUpdates" />
```

to this and it worked

```
<SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory runat="server" ItemId="{@ID}" FieldName="LatestUpdates" ControlMode="Display"/>
```

Comment: can you please advice how i can edit this xsl, i try editing the "AllItems.aspx" page using SP2013, but i can not find such a code "<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"

Comment: Check this link http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/177765.aspx it explains how to convert to XSLT view.

Comment: can you advice on this please?